# How to get an action from a checkbox click in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to give the user a 'show all' option on a page with kaminari pagination

If there are more than 20 rows, the bottom of the page shows

> « First ‹ Prev 1 2   ()       Show all documents

where is () a checkbox

I want to code the page so that I can hide the kaminari pagination if the checkbox is clicked.

I am stuck right now because I can't seem to get the onchange or onclick to work.

```
    <td> <%= paginate @documents %></td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td>Show all documents <%= check_box_tag("Show all on one page", "show_all", true,
                                              :onchange =>   "javascript_tag alert('All is good')"
                                              ) %>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

With the code above, the js popup appears when the page is loaded but does not appear when the checkbox is clicked/changed

My goal is to be able to execute code when a checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `javascript_tag`. Just put the `alert()` function there directly.

The reason is that if you use `javascript_tag`, it will insert a `<script>`  that will actually be executed once a page is loaded. The correct syntax to execute JS in an event from a button is to simply write the actual code there, e.g., a function call, which will only be executed after the button is clicked.